# The BlackHole Bot Trap

Tags: bots, blackhole

I’m trying to use [BlackHole trap outlined here](http://perishablepress.com/blackhole-bad-bots/) on my website, but I always get an error message saying “Error Opening file.”

```
 $fp = fopen($filename, 'r') or die('<p>Error opening file.</p>');
 while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
     if (!preg_match("/(googlebot|slurp|msnbot|teoma|yandex)/i", $line)) {
         $u = explode(' ', $line);
         if ($u[0] == $ipaddress) ++$badbot;
     }
 }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What language is this? Php? Please add the correct tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your first line is as follows:

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'r') or die('<p>Error opening file.</p>');
```

We can pretty quickly deduce that the `fopen()` call is failing. Verify that you're providing the function with a correct file path -- nothing after it matters if the file doesn't open!